# How to make an app close itself completely (and cleanly)

Tags: android, codenameone

I want to add "exit" functionality.

`Display.getInstance().exitApplication();` almost works, but leaves
behind a "ghost" window in the android open applications view.

Comment: it is not `"open applications view"`, but rather `"recent applications view"`, see `Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`

Comment: Even if this is possible: You should not do that. There is a reason android has those views. You can use `NO_HISTORY` flag for single activities that should not show.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you finish all `Activities` and `Services`, and set every other reference to null.

That would leave you with just the Application Singleton alive if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Every `Application` on `android OS`, is like a `User` in `Linux OS`, and every application runs in a `process` which has a `Process ID` assigned to it which application does not know, but we if we kill the process and entire application will stop.

Here is how you can do.

```
 android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

but this would restart your first `activity` of your `application`, as `android` will try to recover the `Application`, you can avoid that by going to home screen like this

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Comment: Your advice may be correct for general android, but it doesn't appear to be relevant to the codenameone environment.

Answer (score 0):

[Display.exitAppliction](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#exitApplication--) is the only way to exit an app but it won't be removed from the task switcher. Thanks to the comment from @david-medenjak I was able to find this:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

To use that just use:

```
android.xactivity=android:noHistory="true"
```

In your build hints and the app won't be in history at all. But as people said this is a pretty bad practice...

FYI in iOS if you include an exit button your app will be rejected by review unless its a "logoff" button. Typical mobile apps never really exit and are only supposed to exit for security purposes.

The OS will kill your app if it needs the resources. Notice that this is important since mobile apps are stopped/restarted often e.g. incoming phone call.

Comment: what are the implications of "no history" that are considered bad?

Comment: interesting about iphones. A few weeks ago my wife was complaining that her battery seemed to be running down awfully fast.  It turned out that every application she had ever run was still running.  After a manual massacre, the battery got better.

Comment: Apps in the history aren't necessarily "running" they can be completely suspended or killed. If you exit the application its truly dead and what you see in the history is exactly that "history". You'd be preventing users from easily returning to your app which is inconvenient and odd. The thing that kills iOS phones is the background processes from specific apps i.e. Facebook. If you block their ability to poll in the background for location/updates battery could improve.